# How to prevent autocomplete from filling in all the input fields on my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#source').keyup(function() {
    var query = $(this).val();
    if (query != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          query: query
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#sourcelist').fadeIn();
          $('#sourcelist').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#source').val($(this).text());
    $('#sourcelist').fadeOut();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#destination').keyup(function() {
    var query = $(this).val();
    if (query != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search1.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          query: query
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#destinationlist').fadeIn();
          $('#destinationlist').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#destination').val($(this).text());
    $('#destinationlist').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with AJAX or even JavaScript. That is just the way auto-complete works as a browser function.

Adding:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

to the HTML of the element(s) that shouldn't be automatically filled in should disable this on the fields you don't want it on.

But, as mentioned on **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)**:

> In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values
>   even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected
>   behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really
>   forcing the no-autocompletion is to assign a random string to the
>   attribute, for example:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

Comment: Most browsers ignore this these days

Comment: the second input field also works for autocomplete but while i'm filling the first input field through autocomplete,the second one is also being filled up with the result of first one.

Comment: Make sure that the two fields don't share the same `name` or `id` attribute values.

Comment: yes i have made two different id and name stil not working